# Finding changing text in Excel or Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, search, google-sheets

hope you can help with an Excel or Google Spreadsheet question.
In one column I have different words, which I would like to search for in a certain area in the spreadshet. Fx. is B3 present from B50:B678 is B4 present from B50:B678 and so on. The text is not an exact match. That means that sometimes the searchwords is placed in the whole sentes. See this data for an excample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MX8WsnwcxEety-sv2ttEcUqgAgEUbpUd_xD18cG20lk/edit#gid=574850130

Hope you can help. With no succes I have tried these formulas:
=ifError(filter($B$775:$B$7887,ifError(search(B4,$B$775:$B$7887),false)))
=IFERROR(IF(UNIQUE(FILTER(B776:B7888,B776:B7888=B3))="text","Found","Not Found"),"Not Found")
=search(B3,J3:J98)

But the formulas don´t work if there is no excact match...Hope you can help
Best regards
Kåre Kildall Rysgaard
Datajournalist, Analystik.dk

Answer (score 0):

In Google Spreadsheet count the number of occurrences of your search string within the test range by embedding the test string within wildcard characters:

```
=if(countif(A$15:A$2100,ʺ*ʺ&A4&ʺ*ʺ)>0,ʺFoundʺ,ʺNot Foundʺ)
```

The answer in Excel is similar but note that double quotes in Excel use a different character to that in Google Spreadsheet:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$15:A$2100,"*"&A4&"*")>0,"Found","Not Found")
```

It appears that Google Spreadsheet uses ANSI 63 for double quotes while Excel uses ANSI 34.